# Missing Libraries/References in MonoDevelop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop

I'm porting an MVC4 project using Visual Studio to an MVC3 project using Monodevelop to host on an Apache Server on CentOS. I'm receiving this error:

```
using System.Data.Objects;
```

The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'.

Has anyone made this move, and if so how did you overcome this reference issue.

Answer (score 1):

For `System.Linq`, you need to add a reference to `System.Core.dll`

For Entity Framework namespaces like `System.Data.Objects`, you need to use the latest beta of Mono and add a reference to `EntityFramework.dll`.

Comment: Ok, let me give that a shot, switched system.linq to system.Data.Linq, will this work for linq to entities or is that System.Core.dll required? Thank you for helping btw

Comment: System.Core did fix the System.linq :) (using latest Beta 3.xx)

Comment: I'm currently using EntityFramework.dll and stil getting that error at the moment. Is there a specific version I should be using?

Comment: Ah EntityFramework.dll isn't listed in the "All" tab inside the mono ref editor, I broght it from the original copy of my Program, no success